# HuBL / Twig: For loop repeating same content (alternative to break needed)

Tags: html, for-loop, twig, hubspot, hubl

I'm using a `for loop` to generate `cards` for each blog post that exists in the system.

The cards generated will have varying widths. A card can be `large` or `small` and to achieve this, I'm using HubL's `cycle` syntax ([doc here](https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/cms/hubl/for-loops#cycle)). A visual example of the card width's I am trying to achieve can be seen here:

[image]

Now, the third card in the first row will not be part of the for loop, it for example, will be an image.

[image]

**The issue I'm having:**

- Cards 1 and 2 show the latest posts (as intended)
- Then, the for loop stops so I can get the lightblue card in (because `Twig` nor `HubL` support the `break` syntax.
- I've started another loop after that in which I have stated `{% if loop.index >=3 %}` - so skip first two items in loop since the latest cards are being displayed in the first loop. But, in the `cycle` I have defined, it will display the wrong card class. Code example below:

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.card{
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 20px;
}

.card--large{
  width: 40%;
}

.card--small{
  width: 20%;
}

.card--filler{
  width: 20%;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <!-- first loop will get two latest cards, first card will be card--large, second card--small -->
  {% for content in contents %}
    {% if loop.index <=2 %}
      <div class="card {% cycle 'card--large','card--small' %}">
        Test
      </div>
    {% endif %}
  {% endif %}
  
  <!-- this is outside the loop -->
  <div class="card card--filler">
    This card is not part of the for loop
  </div>
  
  
  <!-- defining new loop where first two entries should be skipped -->
  {% for content in contents %}
    {% if loop.index >=3 %}
    <div class="card {% cycle 'card--small','card--small','card--large','card--large','card--small','card--small' %}">
      Test
    </div>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
  

</div>
```

In the last loop above, since I'm ignoring the first two posts, it's also ignoring the first two items in the `cycle` parameter. Cards should have the following classes regardless of the loop:

- First card: card--small
- Second card:card--small
- Third card: card--large
- Fourth card: card--large
- Fifth card: card--small
- Sixth card:card--small
- And then it will start from the top again

But, what's happening is:

- First card: card--large
- Second card:card--large
- Third card: card--small
- Fourth card: card--small
- ...

I've also tried `{% if not loop.second %}` instead of `{% if loop.index >=3 %}` but it just get's the same posts again, example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can [set](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/set.html) a sequence array and use it with [the cycle function](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/functions/cycle.html) to cycle through the sequence of classes as for the first loop you can take the part after the second element using [the slice() filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/slice.html) or you can also use the syntax sugar `[start:length]`

**`container.twig`**

```
{% set sequence = ['small','small','large','large','small','small'] %}

<div class="container">

  {% for content in contents[0:3] %}
      {% include 'card.twig' with { card: cycle(sequence[3:], loop.index0) } %}
  {% endfor %}
  
  <div class="card card--filler">
    This card is not part of the for loop
  </div>
  
  {% for content in contents[3:] %}
      {% include 'card.twig' with { card: cycle(sequence, loop.index0) } %}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

[working example](https://twigfiddle.com/gcenw3)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you let the loop go and make an if inside your loop that won't break your cycle but will display your other content?

Mind that `cycle`, [which also exists in Twig](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/cycle.html), by the way, gives the cycled value based on the current loop index, so, having your loop running, even with your "exception card" would fix your issue.

```html
<div class="container">
  {% for content in contents %}
    <div class="card {% cycle 'card--large','card--small','card--small','card--small','card--large'">
      Test
    </div>
    {% if loop.index == 2  }
      <!-- this is outside the loop -->
      <div class="card card--filler">
        This card is not part of the for loop
      </div>
    {% endif %}
  {% endif %}
</div>
```